# Decomposing Signed Permutations

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

Please, how do I decompose a signed permutation into simple transpositions? I need a concrete example to do this. I represented the signed permutation 3 -4 -1 2 in its cycle form (1 3 - 1 3) (2 -4 -2 4) but I cannot decompose this permutation into simple transpositions.